# Python-twitter Logging into to twitter using Oauth-Problem

Tags: python, api, twitter

I am a little bit confused by Oauth.( Heads up I am new to Programming and the Python API for twitter. ) I understand that for Oauth I need a "consumer secret" and "consumer key". Apparently I need to register an app with Twitter to use Oauth authentication and get the consumer secret and consumer key? I am just making a script for personal use and I wish to log in to twitter from my script. I am not trying to make an app or website for an app.

Is there a work around so I can log in to twitter from my script? I understand this was possible with Basic Auth, but now I need to go through a long process where I have to make a website and register just to use my script?

Or maybe I misunderstood the rules and I  can log into twitter from my script without registering an app with Oauth?

Does anyone know how I can log in to twitter from my script now that Baisc Auth is no longer supported. I apologise for my ignorance in advance...

Answer (score 0):

It's mandatory to register your app with Twitter to obtain the "consumer secret" and "consumer key". In this same process you'll be able to create the "access key" and "key secret", wich are the counterparts of the login. All of this are required to create the api instance in Python:

```
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='twitter consumer key',
    consumer_secret='twitter consumer secret',
    access_token_key='the_key_given',
    access_token_secret='the_key_secret')
```

Now, with this information included, your script are capable to access the Twitter API without need to re-authenticate every time. Just include the keys and secret at the API call or as constants. You'll need change this data only if you are gonna to login as someone else. Otherwise, your script access will be always granted.